# django many to many admin shows all and not associated items

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an object structure that looks like so:

Customer -- one to many -- Locations

Locations -- many to many -- Departments

Departments --  one to many --  Objects

here is my models.py (my admin.py is standard):

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Department(models.Model):
    departmentName = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Location(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)


class Object(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
```

The problem is that when I want to set the department for objects I get every department in the django admin drop down.  I even get the departments that are associate with locations of different customers.

Also, when I am setting the department of an object, I get the same list of all available departments, even those associated with different customers.

How can I have the drop down only show me the departments that a  customer supports?

Comment: Update the question with your `models.py` and your `admin.py` for the app(s) involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick one line solution to filter down a many to many relationship is put this line in your admin object:

filter_horizontal = ('departments',)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your own form with filtered queryset

```
class DepartmentAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DepartmentAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customers'].queryset = Customer.objects.filter(...)

    class Meta:
       model = Department


class DepartmentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DepartmentAdminForm
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is to use the formfield_for_manytomany

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey